# UI looks different from the deployed website

Tags: docker, user-interface, debugging, github, next.js

I'm a beginner front-end developer. I recently cloned a github repo for an opensource (sorry can't provide link) and ran it using docker. When I load the UI on localhost only some of the features on the deployed website showed up, but when I used developer tools on chrome there's no error and nothing in the console. When I clicked on the linked displayed on the homepage I [the following error popped up for a few seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nAUr.png) and checking the console again I saw the following errors

```
route-loader.js?361d:91 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/%5Bslug%5D.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
eval @ route-loader.js:113
appendScript @ route-loader.js:96
maybeExecuteScript @ route-loader.js:210
eval @ route-loader.js:267
Promise.then (async)
eval @ route-loader.js:264
withFuture @ route-loader.js:47
loadRoute @ route-loader.js:263
loadPage @ page-loader.js:126
_callee5$ @ router.js:1381
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
fetchComponent @ router.js:1411
_callee3$ @ router.js:1098
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
getRouteInfo @ router.js:1166
_callee$ @ router.js:791
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
change @ router.js:921
push @ router.js:533
instance.<computed> @ router.js:167
linkClicked @ link.js:67
onClick @ link.js:233
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
eval @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22391
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22408
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
route-loader.js:104 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to load script: /_next/static/chunks/pages/%5Bslug%5D.js
    at HTMLScriptElement.script.onerror (route-loader.js:104:36)
script.onerror @ route-loader.js:104
error (async)
eval @ route-loader.js:103
appendScript @ route-loader.js:96
maybeExecuteScript @ route-loader.js:210
eval @ route-loader.js:267
Promise.then (async)
eval @ route-loader.js:264
withFuture @ route-loader.js:47
loadRoute @ route-loader.js:263
loadPage @ page-loader.js:126
_callee5$ @ router.js:1381
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
fetchComponent @ router.js:1411
_callee3$ @ router.js:1098
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
getRouteInfo @ router.js:1166
_callee$ @ router.js:791
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
eval @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
change @ router.js:921
push @ router.js:533
instance.<computed> @ router.js:167
linkClicked @ link.js:67
onClick @ link.js:233
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
eval @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22391
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22408
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/bush-point
```

Sorry if this is vague but what could be the problem? I'm happy to provide more info as long as it doesn't give away what the opensource repo is. Or, any debugging advice is appreciated!

EDIT:
I followed the directory _next/static/chunks/pages and didn't see a  [slug].js file:
[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeK9y.png)

EDIT2:
My page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slBYY.png) when it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDVtW.jpg)

Comment: When you say "an error popped up for a few seconds...I saw the following errors" it seems like you didn't actually include the error.  Could you edit the question to include the text of the error (not a screen shot and not a link, include the text inline in the question) and any code necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi! I editted the question to include the error message in the second picture and unfortunately I can't get the text for the first one because the pop-up was so fast that it disappeared and transitioned to another webpage that I didn't have time to copy it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How would one reproduce the issue?  Something is trying to fetch a script that isn't there, but with only the HTTP 404 message it's difficult to say more.

Comment: is this a publicly available docker image? can we get the image name so that we can reproduce it in our end?

Comment: @tsamridh86 The docker image is publicly available: https://hub.docker.com/r/orcasound/orcasite. I'd appreciate it if you can help me reproduce the issue!

Comment: @DavidMaze The docker image is publicly available: https://hub.docker.com/r/orcasound/orcasite.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have named one of your `pages/` files as `[slug].js` (or at least that's what its evaluating to - see `%5Bslug%5D`

If not, post the contents of your pages directory.

Solve: Rename the file or remove the corresponding files and re-run the build.

Comment: I followed the directory _next/static/chunks/pages and didn't see a  [slug].js file. I updated the screenshot of the directory above:(

Comment: Cloning directly on local both dev and prod builds deploy fine, are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: Does your webpage look like the correct screenshot I put in edit 2? If so, I can walk you through how I got mine and see if you can help? Thanks!

Comment: Otherwise, if your webpage looks the same as mine, could you also let me know please?

Comment: It looks like this - https://cln.sh/ImxFKI - Your screenshot 1 and 2 do not seem from the same route, are you expecting the menu to be centered etc? what specific elements are you looking to match?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You're right, the released version should look like this (https://live.orcasound.net) instead of my screenshot 2. Both of our screenshots only have the 3 ports but the website has more functionalities. What do I need to do to get my localhost look like the actual website?

Comment: It looks like you have to develop and port over these features, live.orcasound.net does not have material-ui, are you asking what styles you need to add ?

Comment: What does it mean to develop and port over these features? I just want to know why (if I cloned the repo successfully), it doesn't look like live.orcasound.net

Comment: you're right! the branch I cloned was not up to date. Problem solved. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thanks! if you liked this or other answers, Please vote them up!